# Installing Macpup on old MacBook 4.1. Where am I going Wrong?

Tags: system-installation, macintosh, elementary-os, puppy-linux, refind

My MacBook is an old white 2008 MacBook 4.1 with 2GB ram Intel Core 2 Duo @ 2.1 Ghz and a 64-bit EFI, I have managed to Install rEFInd into the EFI partition and I am trying to load the MacPup 550 Distro onto the HDD, I would Ideally like MacPup as the only operating system on the HDD.

However when trying to boot from the MacPup live usb created from the iso the USB does not show. This is the case before and after installing rEFInd.

I have managed the following tasks on the troublesome Macbook:

1. Re-installed Mac OSX Lion Several Times
2. Installed Ubuntu from Live Disc + USB (bit sluggish and Right-Click is temperamental, macbook 4.1 has only one mouse button)
3. Run Lubuntu from Live USB + CD (Installation crashes with input/output error at same point every time in both USB and CD live environments I've even replaced the HDD).
4. Installed Remix OS via Live USB lags and functions more like the phone and is not nice for this machine.
5. Installed rEFInd to the EFI (ESP) and booted ubuntu Live cd + USB

I installed rEFInd as it was suggested across multiple websites for installing elementary os on MacBooks and also suggested for installing puppy linux on a macbook unfortunately puppy linux tutorial leads to a broken page.

getting elementary or even puppy to boot should get me on track for macpup. I have tested several different USB drives as well to rule out them being an issue.

I have done all of these separately note: all Attempts have been attempted by single distro live environment USB or CDs (other than mac OSX install that is done by original mac install CD)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, those white MacBook models are supposed to only have a 32-bit EFI; the transition to 64-bit EFI was only made in the first Macbook "Pro" aluminum models (and not in the first batches). My memory can be betraying me here. (I owned a black one, and "owned" two whites ones at my job, also the first aluminium one, and nowadays an i5 from 2012 at job, and an i7 from 2013 at home).

It is an easier avenue to try to track a contemporary BootCamp that supports your hardware and install it; the BootCamp supports legacy boot via "BIOS", and is/was a utility to manage booting into several "legacy" OSes, either be them Windows, Linux or *BSD.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_Camp_(software)

I would also give a try to FreeBSD. It is in a very usable state nowadays and OS/X is supposed to drink from it. Linux supports a larger panoply of hardware, however who knows whether you will get lucky with it.

Comment: Anecdotally, I bought as my travelling laptop a new Lenovo Ideapad 14'' wifi 802.11n ac, 4GB RAM, 32GB SSD, Celeron, for around 150USD. Using FreeBSD 12.0 on it.